# Error when initializing the variable in next line at class scope

Tags: java, oop

When I am trying to compile the following program, I am getting an error but if I write `int i = 3` then it compiles successfully.

```
class A {
    int i;
    i=3; //initializing the variable in next line so error comes
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("hiii..");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't allow you to write statements outside of constructor or methods. Move your line to constructor or any method you want.

Only declarations allows outside of methods and constructor.

As a side note, there is static blocks which allows you to do the same, I don't think you need that in this case.

Give a try reading [JLS # Blocks and Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html)

Comment: but why it works , if i intialize at the the time of declaration i.e int i=3;

Comment: @Dani Updated my post.

Comment: class A {
    int i=3;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("hiii..");
    }
}
But if i write intialize at the time of declaration it perfectly works without writing in method ,constructor or block